# android setOnItemClickListener can't use intent to pass data

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I use listview and rewrite setOnItemClickListener.In setOnItemClickListener(),I use intent to pass data to another activity. But another activity receive null.
The code is:

1. QuerBook.java (send data)

public class QueryBook extends Activity {

```
private List<BookItem> bookList = new ArrayList<BookItem>();
private Bundle saved;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    saved = savedInstanceState;
    setContentView(R.layout.querybook);
    Log.d("Activity1","haha"+getClass().getSimpleName());
    queryBook();
    BookAdapter adapter = new BookAdapter(QueryBook.this, R.layout.bookitem, bookList);
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            Log.d("Activity1",getClass().getSimpleName());
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            BookItem bookItem = bookList.get(position);

            id = bookItem.getId();
            Intent intent = new Intent(QueryBook.this, BookDetail.class);
            intent.putExtra("newid",id);
            //Log.d("bookid","hah id = "+id);


            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

}

2.BookDetail.java (receive data)
public class BookDetail extends Activity {

```
private List<BookItem> bookitemList = new ArrayList<BookItem>();
private int id;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.bookdetail);
    Log.d("Activity",getClass().getSimpleName());
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    id = intent.getIntExtra("newid",-1);
    Log.d("bookid","book get  id is "+id);
 }

The 'id' is always return -1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `onItemClick()` the variable `id` is defined as a `long`. Actually it is an argument in the signature:

```
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
```

So when you call

```
intent.putExtra("newid",id);
```

You are actually putting a `long` item into the "extras" bundle, not an `int`.

This is why, when you call `getIntExtra()` you get -1, because the types don't match.

Comment: Thank you very much!I really appreciate your clarifying answer. I was puzzles by this problem a long time.I also replace intent with Java's write and read method .But its efficiency must lower than intent. In brief ,thanks.

Comment: If my answer was helpful, you should accept it by clicking on the checkmark next to my answer. This is good for you and good for me.